# How is the active class added to the correct nav item inside scroll my event?

Tags: javascript

So I have a single page where the active menu item gets highlighted when you scroll to its corresponding section.

My code works, but I don't understand why, specifically this part:

`document.querySelector('nav a[href="' + anchorID + '"]').classList.add("active");`

1. On window.onscroll the for loop collects all the anchors (`nav a`) from the menu
2. Then I get access to individual anchorIDs (hrefs) with:

`var anchorID = anchorsArray[i].getAttribute("href");`

What I don't understand, is how the `.active`class gets added to the correct anchorID based on the current section inside the viewport — when no comparison is made between the section id and the corresponding anchor href. E.g. the href & section id:

- `<a href="#section-2" class="">Section 2</a>`
- `<section id="section-2"></section>`

..are never compared on scroll.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/zgpzrvns/

All the JS

```js
    (function() {
      var anchorsArray = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
      var sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
      var sectionsArray = [];
     
      // Collect all sections and push to sectionsArray
      for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
        var section = sections[i];
        sectionsArray.push(section);
      }
      
      window.onscroll = function() {
        var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    
        for (var i = 0; i < anchorsArray.length; i++) {
          // Get hrefs from each anchor
          var anchorID = anchorsArray[i].getAttribute("href");
          
          var sectionHeight = sectionsArray[i].offsetHeight;
          var sectionTop = sectionsArray[i].offsetTop;
    
          if (
            scrollPosition >= sectionTop &&
            scrollPosition < sectionTop + sectionHeight
          ) {
            /**
            * I don't understand how querySelector finds & adds the active 
            * class to the correct anchor, when no comparison is made between the 
            * section ID (that is inside current section in viewport) and the 
            * anchors ID from anchorsArray
            */
            document
              .querySelector('nav a[href="' + anchorID + '"]')
              .classList.add("active");
          } else {
            document
              .querySelector('nav a[href="' + anchorID + '"]')
              .classList.remove("active");
          }
        }
      };
    })();
```

**In summary:** how is the `active` class added to correct anchor ID, when the corresponding section ID inside the viewport on scroll (when section ID is never detected inside the scroll event?)

I'm so confused about this, and I bet it's something silly I'm overlooking!

Would greatly appreciate some input! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:
It doesn't need to compare any ids, because on scroll you loop over all anchors in your navigation. For each you check, if the section at the same index is in the viewport. If so, you add the active class.

If you switch the positions of your navigation items, you'll see that it will add the active class to the wrong item, because it just checks the index.

If you need some more explanation, tell me. Going to edit the answer then.

Edit index explanation:

You have your navigation anchors in an array, and also your sections.

```
var anchorsArray = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
var sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
```

You are looping your anchors array

```
for (var i = 0; i < anchorsArray.length; i++) {
```

and then you get the height and top position of your section at the same index as your anchor (variable i)

```
var sectionHeight = sectionsArray[i].offsetHeight;
var sectionTop = sectionsArray[i].offsetTop;

if (
    scrollPosition >= sectionTop &&
    scrollPosition < sectionTop + sectionHeight
) {
```

and then you set the active class if its true, or remove it, if its false.

So on each scroll your code does the following:

Get anchor one -> check if section one is in range -> If yes -> add active -> else remove active

Get anchor two -> check if section two is in range -> If yes -> add active -> else remove active

Get anchor three -> ... and so one

Comment: Thank you. Regarding: “For each you check, if the section at the same index is in the viewport. ” — this is what I don't get. How does it know if the section in in the viewport at the *same* index as the corresponding anchor that gets the active class? It sounds like there is a comparison, but not between IDs?

I don't know why I don't get it :S

Comment: @Capax edited my answer for a more detailed explanation

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Ziegler. Now I get it! This is the part I totally overlooked: the index variable I get from sectionHeight & sectionTop are from the looped anchorsArray[i] — I was looking at the sectionsArray loop outside of the scroll event (thinking that sectionHeight[i] & sectionTop[i] got their index variable from *that* collection, not the one inside the anchor loop!